# `az storage account list` returns an empty list although it had worked in the past

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cli

I have logged in using

```
az login
```

But now

```
az storage account list
```

returns an empty list.  I am using a number of different accounts presently on `synapse` and `azure` including from within the local `Pycharm` and on the `ms.portal`,  `synapse` and `dev` websites.  So why has this stopped working?

Here is my version

```
az --version
azure-cli                         2.53.0

core                              2.53.0
telemetry                          1.1.0

Dependencies:
msal                            1.24.0b2
azure-mgmt-resource             23.1.0b2

Python location '/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.53.0/libexec/bin/python'
Extensions directory '/Users/stephenboesch/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Darwin) 3.10.13 (main, Aug 24 2023, 22:48:59) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.
```

Here is `az account show`

```
$az account show
{
  "environmentName": "AzureCloud",
  "homeTenantId": "*****b47",
  "id": "****499",
  "isDefault": true,
  "managedByTenants": [],
  "name": "Azure Portal Telemetry Reporting",
  "state": "Enabled",
  "tenantId": "*******b47",
  "user": {
    "name": "my-name@my-company.com",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which subscription are you connecting to ? `az account show` to check the subscription.

Comment: @Thomas  added a redacted output

Comment: Hi @WestCoastProjects try using this comment `az account set --subscription <name or id>` in your terminal and try again with comment.

Comment: so this `Azure Portal Telemetry Reporting` subscription: is it the one containing the storage account ?

Comment: @Venkatesan  `az account set --subscription ` fixed the problem, please update your answer

Comment: @WestCoastProjects, it's always recommended to use `az account list` followed by `az account set -s <sub-name/id>` to set the right subscription.

Comment: @harshavmb  Please provide link / guidance to docs describing these "best practices".  That would be v helpful . Thx!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account/subscription?view=azure-cli-latest @WestCoastProjects

Comment: @harshavmb  That's not a general best practices. Specifically where is it stated  that it is "always recommended to do `az account list` follweed by `az account set`" ?

Comment: How do you say `That's not a general best practices`? You didn't even know to which subscription it was defaulted before but now say its not a best practice. I meant to say if you list all subscriptions you have access to & then you can choose which subscription you would like to work with. Isn't this a recommended approach? I never said its the best practice.

Comment: pls see my prior comment that specifically asks for "best practices". I assumed your subsequent response were on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> az storage account list returns an empty list.

I also get the same empty list in my environment when I try with all the below commands.

```
az account clear 
az login
az account set --subscription "xxxxx"
```

When I tried with the same command **`az storage account list`**.

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> az storage account list                                           
[]
PS C:\Users\xxx>
```

The above command takes a particular resource group that doesn't have a storage account in your environment.

Check with **`az config get`** it will show if you have a default resource group.

If it is there try to remove it by using the below command:

```
az config unset defaults.group
```

The above command removes the default resource group.

Now I ran the same command, and it shows me all storage accounts:

**Output:**
[image]

**Update:**

Please try with again with `az login` and `az account set --subscription "xxxxx"` commands in your environment.

**Reference:**

[az storage account list is not listing all storage accounts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22465) by evelyn-ys.

Comment: Thx for that recommendation. I did the `az config unset defaults.group` and it was seemingly successful. The `az storage accounts list` still came up empty though.

Comment: `az account set --subscription`  fixed the problem, please update your answer. And now I can use `az storage fs directory download` again. Awesome!

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Updated.